# Do you use singular or plural in names of arrays, maps, sets, etc.?

Tags: variables, naming-conventions

I have a quick question that is not particular technical, but I sometimes wonder what's better ...

Do you use singular or plural in names of arrays, maps, sets, etc.? Example:

Singular

```
1  std::map<string,double> age;
2  age["diego maradonna"] = 49;
```

Plural

```
1  std::map<string,double> ages;
2  ages["diego maradonna"] = 49;
```

In the plural version, the second line isn't nice (because you're looking up the age, not the ages of Maradonna). In the singular version, the first line sounds kind of wrong (because the map contains many ages).

Comment: You've got your examples mixed up. I tend to use plural names for arrays and other types of lists.

Comment: This poll should really be community wiki.

Comment: @Neil Yes, I thought of this, but didn't see the option to set that.

Comment: @Frank: if you edit it, there will be a "community wiki" checkbox somewhere toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: I thought I was the only one with that singular-plural dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

Singular for instances, plural for collections.

Answer (score 3):

For maps, I will typically even go a step further and name them in terms of both their keys and values (ex. agesByPersonNames). This is especially helpful if you have a map of maps.

Answer (score 2):

Plurals. I use the same kind of names for SQL tables. The case of:

```
ages["diego maradonna"] = 49;
```

should be read as "in the collection of ages, find me the one that belongs to maradonna and change it to 49"

Answer (score 2):

I would use `nameToAgeMap["diego maradonna"]`, so it's obvious what you put in (a name) and get out (an age), it reads nicely in assignments: `nameToAgeMap["diego maradonna"] = 49;` which could be read as "put 49 into the name-to-age map for Diego Maradonna".